# Math rendering with Firefox 16.0.2

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm noticing some differences between how the math is getting rendered in edit mode vs. after the edit is done.

[Case in point:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49107/ac-and-dc-resistance)

[image: Edit mode]

In edit mode, the rendering looks fine. Look what happens after I save the edits:

[image: After saving]

It looks like whitespace needed for readability is getting removed, leading to the plaintext appearing over top of the math markup.

EDIT: Rendering looks correct on my home PC with Firefox 17.0 ... strange...

Comment: Not sure if you fixed it somehow, but I cannot reproduce it on my system Mozilla Firefox 16.0.2 - ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24

Comment: I didn't do anything.